# Angular 2 get element data and remove it

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new to angular 2 and want to get data from html element and remove html element from DOM.

Basically I my below code when user clicks on delete icon I want to collect `{{i.firstName}}` value, open a popup with statement 'Are your sure you want to delete `{{i.firstName}}` ?'. If the user clicks yes then whole TR tag means entire row needs to be deleted from the DOM.

I was going throught some other reference i found some one using `ElementRef` but I was not able to progress on this. can anyone give me a reference video or link where I can learn more about `ElementRef`.

```js
deleted(event){
    console.log(event.target.parent.innerHTML);
  }
```

```html
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let i of array; let j = index" [id]="j">
        <td>{{i.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.age}}</td>
        <td>{{i.address}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleted($event)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the current index along with click event.

```
(click)="deleted($event, j)"
```

and remove the relevant row of data from data(array) retrieved in `ngFor`. `ngFor` will remove that relevant DOM element automatically.

```
delete(event, index) {
  if(window.confirm('really removing current row?')) {
    this.array.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

add an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pgXKvyuc71g0eBp9tfn6?p=preview) about removing elements at component using ViewChildren.

Comment: thnks, I am using ng2-bs3-modal so need to collect value i in one function and remove element in other function ... can we do something like we do in jquery like (this).parent().find('#username').text(). basically i want to traverse html elements using this keyword

Comment: @Jay you can do it with ViewChildren. But ngFor will add the relevant DOM again when angular detected changes which means you still have to remove data from the array same to the way I recommend.

Comment: can you please give a reference example

Comment: thanks it really helped me ... need to know what is _results[index] ? is that a method of query string? as i dont see any import or instance being created for the same .... if i have to target an element eg ...i wrote console.log(this.testRows._results[index].nativeElement); and i got output as <tr><td>2</td><td>name2</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr> ... now i want to get name2 text ... do i need to use jquery or any standard angualar property

Comment: i have done it console.log(this.testRows._results[index].nativeElement.children[1].innerHTML);   .... thanks for the help

Comment: @Jay sorry for the late response, the `_result` is a set which contains target elments. you can get what you want by it's index.